# Custom macro logic

Tags: c, macros, undefined-behavior, post-increment, pre-increment

I was doing some exercises online and I was given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUSTOM_ADD(x) ++x+++x

int main() {
    int a=6;
    int b=8;
    
    printf("%d",a + CUSTOM_ADD(a+b)+b);
    return 0;
}
```

I figured out that the addition a+b(14) is passed on the macro and it opens like that
++14+ ++14 =30
then the final result should be 44.
I also considered that the macro might expand like that:
++14++ +14
Which would be 29, since the value would be incremented after the usage and the final result could be 43.
I was not sure which one would be right, so I ran the code and the output was 47.
I just could not find anyway to reach the result.

Comment: Try using something like `gcc -E file.c` (if you're using `gcc`) to view the preprocessor output.  It might not be what you're expecting.

Comment: `+++` is parsed as `++ +`, not `+ ++`.

Comment: That's a really stupid macro. Find a different place to learn that doesn't try to teach you nonsense.

Comment: @AviBerger: It is entirely normal and proper to present such code in a lesson on things to avoid in C and why it is not defined. Stack Overflow commonly gets questions like this asked with no context. The context in which it is presented may be fine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, In the context of things to avoid, it would be fine.

Comment: By using the `-E` argument to your compiler, you can see what the preprocessor has expanded the macro to.  https://godbolt.org/z/KMfPPhMnb  (I've removed the `#include` statement due to the amount of unrelated text it produces.)

Answer (score 4):

Macro processing works by replacing grammatical tokens.

In `#define CUSTOM_ADD(x) ++x+++x`, the replacement list is parsed to the tokens `++` `x` `++` `+` `x`. When determining the next token, the rule is to take the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a token, so analyzing `+++` produces `++` first, then `+`.

In `printf("%d",a + CUSTOM_ADD(a+b)+b);`, macro replacement results in `printf("%d",a + ++ a + b ++ + a + b + b);`.

The second argument to `printf` is parsed as `a + (++a) + (b++) + a + b + b`. The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard because it both modifies `a`, in `++a`, and uses the value of `a` without sequencing between them. The same problem exists with `b++` and `b`.

In ordinary modern C implementations, it is not uncommon that the above expression would produce a value of `a+a+a+b+b+b` as if `a` and `b` had been incremented somewhere in the sequence of additions, with `a` incremented at least once before its last use. Thus, with `a` starting at 6 and `b` starting at 8, it could produce 42 (6+6+7+8+8+8, with `a` incremented after the first addition of 6+6 and `b` incremented after all of them) or 48 (7+7+7+9+9+9) or anything in between. However, another potential result is that compiler analysis determines the behavior of the code is not defined by the C standard, and therefore a well-written program would never transfer program control to this execution path, so it may be removed from the program entirely.

One reason the rule exists is that, for some types, updating a variable requires multiple operations, such as for wide integers implemented using multiple operations on small processors. And a compiler could not always tell whether an expression was both updating a variable and using the same variable, as when a pointer is used. For example, in `++*p + *q`, the compiler generally does not know whether `p` and `q` point to the same thing. If they did, and multiple steps are needed to increment the variable, the compiler could generate instructions that are incrementing `*p` interleaved with instructions that are fetching its value for `*q`. The C standard committee decided to put the onus on programmers to avoid this.

Comment: @FiddlingBits it is

Comment: Sorry, didn't read far enough.

Comment: I didn't get it. You said it the macro is parsed as `++x++x+`, in other words `++(a+b)++ +(ab)`
So the printf should be parsed as `a+ ++(a+b) + ++(ab) +b`
What did I get wrong?

If the behavior is not defined by the C standard, what should I expect from the output?

Comment: @user16881149: In `CUSTOM_ADD(a+b)`, the argument to the macro is `a+b`. It is not `(a+b)`. No parentheses are put into the replacement tokens. The token `x` is replaced with the tokens `a` `+` `b`. It is not replaced with the tokens `(` `a` `+` `b` `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the expression `a + b` used in this macro invocation

CUSTOM_ADD(a+b)

in the defined macro instead of the name `x`

```
#define CUSTOM_ADD(x) ++x+++x
```

and you will get

```
++a + b++ +a + b
```

As a result this statement

```
printf("%d",a + CUSTOM_ADD(a+b)+b);
```

will look like

```
printf("%d",a + ++a + b++ +a + b + b);
```

that invokes undefined behavior because the variables `a` and `b` are read and changed within one expression.

That is expressions like that

```
a + ++a
```

and

```
b++ + b
```

have undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (J.2 Undefined behavior)

> — A side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a
> different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
> using the value of the same scalar object (6.5).

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get why the macro expands on ++a + b++ +a + b and not on ++(a+b)++ +a+)

Comment: @user16881149 bcause a + b substistues x not ( a + b )

Comment: @user16881149 You need to remember that the preprocessor implements simple textual substitution -- it knows nothing about `C` language/syntax or operator precedence.